# How can I insert my dummy data into my sqlite table - iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to insert dummy data into my sqlite table. How could I insert this properly and what am I doing wrong? Thanks, all help and advice is appreciated

```
+(void)setAllValues {
    static sqlite3_stmt *insertStatement;
    const char *sqlInsert = "insert into session_descriptions (sessionID, sessionTitle, sessionDescription) values (1, 'Programming Title' 'Programming description')";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2([DBHelper getDB], sqlInsert, -1, &insertStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Insert statement not working");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement);
    sqlite3_close([DBHelper getDB]);
}
```

Comment: Did you open the database? Does the table exist? Where's all of your error checking?

Comment: Yes the database is opened elsewhere and the table does exist. I will re-check and get back to you, thanks

Comment: If you open the database elsewhere then you shouldn't close it here.

Comment: Is it better practice to leave it open here and close it after I call these methods where I opened the database?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

1. You're checking to see if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed, but not bothering to check why it failed. This is accomplished by logging `sqlite3_errmsg`:

   ```
   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2([DBHelper getDB], sqlInsert, -1, &insertStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
       NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg([DBHelper getDB]));
   }
   ```

   It's important to check `sqlite3_prepare_v2` for success, and if not, immediately log `sqlite3_errmsg`, because most SQLite errors are detected during the preparation of the statement (and if you do any further SQLite calls before examining the error message, any meaningful error message might be replaced with some less-illuminating message).
2. Even if the prepare succeeded, you're not performing the SQL query. So after the above "prepare" statement, you should "step" it, in order to perform it:

   ```
   if (sqlite3_step(insertStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
       NSLog(@"step failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg([DBHelper getDB]));
   }
   ```

   Do this after `sqlite3_prepare_v2` but before `sqlite3_finalize`.
3. You are closing the database. This is a bit suspect because you generally want to leave the database in whatever state it was when you called this routine. So, I'd might expect the database to not be open, in which case, this routine would open, prepare, step, finalize, and then close. Or I might expect the database to be open already, in which case you'd merely prepare, step, and finalize, but not close the database, leaving the database in the same state as it was when you called this routine.

   As an aside, I would advise opening the database once and keeping it open as long as the app is alive, but either approach works. Just make sure your opens and closes are properly balanced.
4. Your `INSERT` statement is missing a comma.